# Cron Job with header Location redirect in PHP

Tags: php, header, include, cron, absolute-path

I have a cron job for loading a same file for many times using php `header` function

The script is working fine when it runs from the browser but when make it cron i face some problems.

The code is the bellow. My file mane is `sample.php`

```
<?php
$id = $_request['id'];
if($id==""){
$id=0;
}
header("Location:sample.php?id=$id");    
?>
```

But header not working for me.

I am already change my coding format

```
$base = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)); // now $base contains "app"

header("Location:".$base."?id=$id");
```

But its not working also.

My Cron Acknowledgement mail only i receive. But the mail contains Errors.

My mail is given below

```
Status: 302 Moved Temporarily
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.21
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=ce4d2ee31140477510bfc780c6d0ce48; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location:/home/xxxxxx/public_html/admin/xxxx.php
```

Any one guide me. How can i set this type of cron jobs

How can i redirect in my cron file. because i am load big size of datafeed files. so only i am asking

Comment: What do you expect the effect of a `header` to be in a browser-less cron job context?!

Comment: Hi @deceze I need to redirect using cron job

Comment: Redirect who? Redirect what?

Comment: Because of many datafeed zip files get from another ftp to put into my server. so loading process is over loaded. so only i am not using for loops. redirect using header

Comment: Understand that a `header` sets an HTTP header. When running a script from the command line or a cron job, there is no HTTP request involved! You cannot "redirect" because there's nothing to redirect. You're missing something in your big picture how this stuff works here.

Answer (score 2):

corn run as console not run as browser you can not send header for corn

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run an external script using PHP in a cronjob, take a look at curl. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 1):

As other people have said, your cron has no concept of headers, it just runs the script.

If you want to be able to do something like this then look into using [Lynx](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lynx) - it will allow you to call your `cron` > `lynx` > `website`. You can also look into curl if you want a PHP solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can not send header if you are running script using cron tab. Crontab runs in console not in a browser so there is no meaning sending header using crontab.

Comment: Hi @Mahendra How can i send using Crontab? please Explain

Comment: How can i redirect in my cron file. because i am load big size of datafeed files. so only i am asking

Comment: like I said you it is not possible. why you need header there anyway ? what script you are running on redirected page ? What ever action you want to perform you will have to write script it cron file itself. header() is not gonna work in cron tab.

Comment: Because of many datafeed zip files get from another ftp to put into my server. so loading process is over loaded. so only i am not using for loops. redirect using header

Answer (score 0):

Based on what Anyone has said, I checked the PHP manual and came up with this function to do just that, which by the way, is what I was searching for as well.

call it from inside your cron script:

```
if ( $getThisUrlAgain = cURLget ( "myCronJobUrl" ) ) {
    // do stuff with $getThisUrlAgain... 
} else {
    // do something if fail
}




function cURLget($url) {
    
    if( !cURLcheckBasicFunctions() ) return false;
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    
    if ($ch) {
        
        ob_start();
        
        if( !curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url) ) {
            
            curl_close($ch); // to match curl_init()
            return false;
        }
        
        if( !curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0) ) return false;
        
        if( !curl_exec($ch) ) return false;
        
        curl_close($ch);
        
        $retval = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        
        return ( $retval ? $retval : true);
        
    }
    
    else return false;
    
}

function cURLcheckBasicFunctions() {
    if( !function_exists("curl_init") &&
        !function_exists("curl_setopt") &&
        !function_exists("curl_exec") &&
        !function_exists("curl_close") ) return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```