# PHP header() redirect is working when I serve the page from VS code, but not when I fire the script from a cron job or a Cli

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a simple PHP script that queries MySQL DB and deletes(unlinks) file(s) from an uploads folder when a condition (expiry timestamp) is met. Then it redirects to another PHP script. I have set up a cron job to run the first script automatically, this works fine and deletes the files where needed from the uploads folder, but it does not redirect when my if-else statement gets triggered. If I manually paste the file path to the browser, the script runs, deletes and redirects as I would expect. (Also will not redirect if I run the PHP file from the CLI). Any help would be much appreciated.

```
include_once 'db.php';

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql = "SELECT name FROM files WHERE expiry <= '$date'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo('Could not get data: '.mysqli_error());
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $delete = ("assets/uploads/{$row['name']}");
    if (file_exists($delete)) {
        unlink($delete);
    } else {
        header("Location: expire.php", 
            true, 301);
        exit();
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Slightly o/t, but why do you continue to try to retrieve data if you get `false` back from the query? An `exit()` would be useful there, I think.

Comment: Isn't a header redirect a browser instruction? I haven't tried it myself, but this seems to agree: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633829/cron-job-with-header-location-redirect-in-php

Comment: Trying to use a location header in this scenario could only make sense, if you called the script not via CLI in the first place - but with a cron setup that utilizes `wget` to request the script _via HTTP(S)_, or something similar. But on CLI no HTTP is involved, so it makes no sense to try and do an _HTTP redirect_ in that environment.

Comment: As an aside: `mysqli_error()` won't tell you any errors because you forgot to include the connection object as a parameter to it (as per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)). But there's a far better way to get errors from mysqli than clunkily having boilerplate testing code after every command - see [How to get the actual mysqli error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/5947043) for details.

Comment: You have an error. [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone, script now working perfectly with @ADyson advice. I will try to do better next time ;0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `header` function just issues a HTTP response header to be sent back to a client when the script ends. Clearly, that only makes sense in the context of a HTTP request.

And again hopefully it's self-evident that running the script via CLI or cron is not a HTTP context. Therefore, issuing any kind of response header, such as `Location`, won't have any effect. Remember that the kind of redirect you commonly see on websites is actually done *by the browser* - the server merely tells the browser (via the Location header) where it wants the browser to go next.

In your CLI/cron situation, if you want to run another script, one option is simply to `require` it, e.g.

```
else {
   require "expire.php";
   exit();
}
```

This will mean it executes as a continuation of the current script.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation and help, I understood that the redirect would only work in the browser environment. I had a not seeing the wood for the trees moment. I also appreciate the mysqli_error() tips, would upvote but I have only just started with stackoverflow (need a few more reputation points) Thanks again ;-)

Comment: No worries, you can still mark the answer as "accepted", by clicking the tick mark next to it so it goes green :-)

Comment: Thanks, clicked and now green 